# Hide running apps

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

I have a Windows 8.1 HP 64 bit computer, and when I open an app it displays it on the taskbar. Before it doesn't display it on the taskbar, the only way to get to it is to slide your mouse to the top left corner of the screen, but now it does. Now you can click the app from the taskbar, which I don't want it to. Is there anyway to hide the apps? I will appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your meaning very well but [THIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rbtray/files/latest/download) is an application that can move any program to system tray.just extract and run it and send to tray by right clicking on minimize button on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the taskbar, go to `Properties`, and uncheck `Show Windows Store apps on the taskbar`, as shown below:

[image: Taskbar Windows Store apps]